# Can different entity managers manage the same persistence context in Java SE?

Tags: jpa

I'm reading Pro JPA 2. It has the following figure:

[image]

Per the figure, many entity managers can point to the same persistence context. I'm trying to accomplish this in Java SE:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EmployeeService");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();
            
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    
    Employee employee = new Employee(1);
    employee.setName("Bob");
    employee.setSalary(100000);
    
    em.persist(employee);

    System.out.println("em" + em.find(Employee.class, 1));          
    System.out.println("em all Employees " + em.createQuery("SELECT e from Employee e", Employee.class).getResultList());

    System.out.println("em2 Employee" + em2.find(Employee.class, 1));
    System.out.println("em2 all Employees " + em2.createQuery("SELECT e from Employee e", Employee.class).getResultList());

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    em2.close();
    emf.close();
```

The output is:

```
em Employee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)
em all Employees[Employee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)]
em2 Employee null
em2 all Employees[]
```

So, it appears that `em` and `em2` are pointing to different persistence contexts. Is there a way to have different entity managers manage the same persistence context in Java SE?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question or what you are trying to do. Why would you want a separate but apparently duplicate EntityManager context, or break the ACID nature of the database for this. An EntityManager IS the context. It is a unit of work, storing all your changes and managed entities to be synchronized with the database. Any other EntityManager should not see any changes from each other until the transaction commits. One EM may have many contexts as it can span multiple logical database transactions sequentially.

Comment: @Chris - I'm trying to confirm my understanding of the relationship between entity manager and persistence context. Per the Pro JPA 2 book that I'm reading, the author notes that one persistence context may be managed by multiple entity managers. I would like to confirm that through using Java SE code but not sure how. The OP has code of my failed attempt. I'm essentially asking how I would change that code to demonstrate this relationship. That is, I want to write code to demonstrate that entity manager A and entity manager B can manage the same persistence context Z.

Comment: You'll have to look at the books definitions of what a persistence context is then (I don't have it handy). I'm guessing because it is container specific; the container gives you an EM wrapper 'over' the context, so if you have multiple beans in the same transactional context (with an injected EntityManager using the @PersistenceContext annotation), they will have the same 'context' under them and see each others changes. This is handled by the container, changing in/out the provider specific EntityManager used under the covers so it can control the transactions and injection

Comment: In SE though, no, you are going to get a new and entirely independent EntityManagers for each emf.createEntityManager(); it is required by the spec. The EMF doesn't track EntityManagers, so it would be up to your application - but doing so is dangerous as they are not thread safe (and there is no logical persistence context you can reuse to write your own to make one thread safe). This might help add some to the book if it isn't covering it (I thought it did and will have to pick up a copy) https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-persistence-context

Comment: @Chris - Thanks for your comments. I've already read that web page & it helped my understanding. I'm only on Chapter 2 of the book. The book's definition of persistence context is the "set of all entity instances managed by a specific entity manager."

Comment: @Chris - And also from the book: "The part that may come as a surprise is that many entity managers can point to the same persistence context. We have talked only about an entity manager and its persistence context, but later on you will see that there may in fact be multiple references to different entity managers all pointing to the same group of managed entities." So, perhaps, the book will tell me later what you said about Java SE...  i.e., that EntityManager has a one-to-one relationship with persistence context when using Java SE.

Comment: @Chris - Your comment "In SE though, no, you are going to get a new and entirely independent EntityManagers for each emf.createEntityManager(); it is required by the spec" answers my question. If you post this as an answer along with a link to the spec stating such, I'll accept it as answering my question. Thanks again for your comments on this.

Comment: I can't give you the link, but it is section 7.1 of the JPA 2.0 specification that details persistence contexts and the relationship of EntityManagers (and why container managed is different from SE/application managed EMs)

Comment: @Chris - OK. Thanks for indicating the section within the spec. I read it and it makes sense. That answers my question. If you would like to post this in the form an answer, I'll accept it.